# BusyIndicator for TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem, busyindicator

I'm working with a TabControl which has a few TabItems. Inside these TabItems, there are several charts being bound to a large data source. So, every time the user tries to navigate between the tabs, the system would freeze to take a few seconds to load the contents of the tab. Also, these charts were configured and bound to the data as soon as the system starts. Not when the user clicks the tabs.

I would like to show the Loading.... logo with a transparent background while the user waits. But because of all of these charts were configured at the start of the system (before the UI shows up), I cannot show the BusyIndicator at this stage. It seems like the UI is taking some time to prepare these charts because there are no events which tries to call the backend side except the two-way binding.

My TabControl looks like this:

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabMain"
 Grid.RowSpan="2"
 ....
 ....
 Style="{DynamicResource TabControl}">
 <TabItem x:Name=".." DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}}" ....>
 <TabItem x:Name=".." ....>
 ....
</TabControl>
```

I've been finding a way to show the BusyIndicator at the appropriate time without being have to hard-code the delay time. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't implement the data loading asynchronous. That's why the UI is unresponsive during this time. You should make the data loading asynchronous. Then you can show an overlay in the `TabControl` to show a busy indicator. All you need is a property e.g. `IsBusy` to toggle the visibility of this overlay.

Comment: @BionicCode Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, you're correct. The data loading wasn't implemented asynchronously. Actually, I inherited someone else's code and I didn't have too much choice. Can the overlay be implemented without making the data loading asynchronous?

Comment: Do you start the loading procedure? You can easily wrap the synchronous code. You can create an overlay independent from the data loading. The problem is that in worst case the overly will display when the data is loaded because the loading is blocking the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SelectionChanged` event and add a loading logo, `Rectangle` in this example.

XAML

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabMain" SelectionChanged="tabMain_SelectionChanged"
 Grid.RowSpan="2"
 ....
 ....
 Style="{DynamicResource TabControl}">
 <TabItem x:Name=".." DataContext="{Binding Source= {StaticResource Locator}}" ....>
 <TabItem x:Name=".." ....>
 ....
</TabControl>
<Rectangle x:Name="LoadingLogo" Fill = "White" Visibility="Collapsed" Opacity=0.5/>
```

C#

```
private void tabMain_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Source is TabControl) //if this event fired from TabControl then enter
    {
            //show loading logo
            LoadingLogo.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            //hide the loading logo with lower priority, so that it closes after UI finished loading
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(()=> { LoadingLogo.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; }));
    }
}
```

More info about [Dispatcher.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke?view=netframework-4.8).

In the case of `Rectangle` not showing due to UI loading, you might want to use a borderless translucent `Window` as your loading logo.

Comment: Thanks Wil. It works like a charm with the border-less transparent window. You're a real lifesaver.

Comment: But there's a problem with the Window. Whenever I tried to show the window with
 `window.show()` the `TabMain_SelectionChanged` event is being triggered twice. And it got navigated back to the previous Tab.

Comment: You might need to check call stack to find out what is triggering the event twice.

Comment: I got it now. I just used the `Visibility` property of the `Window` instead of the `window.show()` method. It works swell. Thanks, Wil.

Answer (score 1):

You should have provided a minimal reproduction so people trying to help can prove their code without spending hours.

It seems you're not binding viewmodels to give your tabitems but they have datacontext set.

What I guess is happening is the user chooses to navigate. The new tabitem is rendered using it's data.  That rendering takes time.

The tabcontrol inherits from selector and hence has the selectionchanged event.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged?view=netframework-4.8

You could handle that and show your busy indicator.

```
private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Source is TabControl)  // in case you have a combo or something inside it
    {
       // Make your throbber visible
    }
}
```

There is a complication here though - and again a minimal reproducible sample would have helped you out because I could check what happens. But I can't.

You might find your UI thread is busy rendering that tabitem and your throbber doesn't show up.  In which case you'll have to work out how to delay presenting your data to the 
tabitem when it's chosen.

Once your tabitem shows up you then need to hide that throbber by setting visibility collapsed. One way to do that is to defer that process until the dispatcher isn't busy.

```
        Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(new Action(() => { // Make throbber collapse; })
            , DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Comment: Hi Andy. Sorry I couldn't provide the minimal reproduction. Thanks for your answer. It really makes me understand the concept.